# Is it possible to know which editor git is going to use programatically?

Tags: git, editor

Is it possible to know which editor git is going to use programmatically? Something like this is possible?

```
$git which editor
/usr/bin/nano
```

Basically, I wanted to invoke a custom editor only for git commit messages. So if file name is '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG', I will invoke something else, otherwise I want to fallback to default git editor.

I know that git uses `$GIT_EDITOR`, `core.editor`, `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR` in order to choose an editor. But all of these are not present, I don't know what to do. [Here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) it says, it uses `vi`. But in my machine, it uses `nano`. Hence, it is not really reliable to hardcode that.

Hence, how to know which editor will git use programmatically? If not directly from git, is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the command

```
git var GIT_EDITOR
```

It outputs the value using exactly that algorithm that Git would use to call an editor regardless of the way an editor is configured. If none of the `$GIT_EDITOR`, `core.editor`, `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR` are set it outputs some sensible default.

When nothing is set on my Debian Linux system it outputs `editor` where `/usr/bin/editor` is an (indirect) symlink to `vim.gtk3`. On your system the chain of symlinks is probably pointed to `nano`.

If you want to run "the same editor Git would call" to edit a file `filename` run this:

```
`git var GIT_EDITOR` filename
```

or

```
$(git var GIT_EDITOR) filename
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't even knew there was a `git var` command. Just a quick follow up, to make use of this, I need to unset my git editor while invoking this command. How to do that? `git -c --unset core.editor var GIT_EDITOR`, `git -c core.editor var GIT_EDITOR` and `git -c core.editor= var GIT_EDITOR` did not work.

Comment: No way. With `git -c` you can set a config value but cannot unset. The only way to unset is permanent `git config --unset`. Why do you want to unset it (even temporary)? `git var GIT_EDITOR` intended to get you the current value.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I intend to use a different editor for commit msg. To do that, my idea was to set `core.editor` with a script that invokes a different editor based on file name. To fall back to git's editor, it needs to know which editor to use. But since I've set `core.editor` to my script, it `GIT_EDITOR` will always return my editor - unless, I'm able to unset `core.editor` temporarily. Now I will just wrap that invocation with unset and set then.

Comment: Aha, I see. That would be hard to solve. I dare to suggest a different route. Unset `git config --unset core.editor` and set environment variable `export GIT_EDITOR=editor_script`; set it in your `~/.bash_profile` to be permanent and in all open shells (or do `. ~/.bash_profile` in all open shells). In your script when you want to ask Git for the default editor unset the variable: `unset GIT_EDITOR; $(git var GIT_EDITOR) filename`